# Is there a better implementation for the string function MID or is there a better style of implementation for VBA that is quicker

Tags: excel, string, ms-access, vba

I have script that calls 'MID' (16N) times and it takes around 4 minutes to execute when N = 43. I am not sure why it is taking so long it is a calling a String of ~440 characters each time:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
If Sheets.count = 1 Then
a = ActiveWorkbook.Name    
ChDir "C:\"
MsgBox "Be Prepared to a text file", vbExclamation, _
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
Workbooks.OpenText FileToOpen, Origin:=xlWindows, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
x = ActiveWorkbook.Name     'SO # workbook
Workbooks(x).Sheets(1).Copy after:=Workbooks(a).Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
Windows(x).Activate         'SO # workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close
'I also need to declare the value of each column with each 'with' statement
Range("A1").Select
With Rows("1:1")
.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
With Range("A1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
'Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("B1")   
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("C1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("D1")   
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("E1")   
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("F1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("G1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit    
With Range("H1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With    
Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit    
With Range("I1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("I:I").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("J1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("K1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("L1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Range("M1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("M:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit    
With Range("N1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With    
Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.AutoFit   
With Range("O1")    
.Font.Bold = True
End With    
Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit   
With Range("P1")    
End With    
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit    
With Range("Q1")
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Columns("Q:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Dim i As Long
Dim current As String
'Dim Strings As Variant
Dim count As Integer
Dim cell As Integer
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.count, 16))    
For i = 2 To Rows.count 'foreach row
    current = Cells(i, 1).Value
    cell = 0 '0
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 3, 7) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 9, 7) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 16, 5) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 40, 10) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 50, 8) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 58, 8) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 66, 4) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 70, 2) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 100, 20)
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 120, 6) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 126, 10) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 136, 10) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 146, 12) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 158, 12) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 170, 12) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 194, 255) 
    cell = cell + 1
    rng(i, cell + 1).Value = Mid(current, 449, 255) 
    cell = cell + 1
Next i
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(rng(1, 1), rng(Rows.count, cell)), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Macro has finished running"
MsgBox "Data is now in Excel format and can be saved to a new file.", _
vbExclamation, "MORE CHOICES"
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Else
   MsgBox "Additional tab already exists. Only MACROS tab should exist in       workbook prior to running macro.", _
vbExclamation, "**  Additional tab already exists  **"
 End If  
 End Sub
```

I have been using [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) source as a reference for to try to reduce the time it takes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your original post using the edit.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `MID()` function call that is causing the issue? You are going to have to post more code to give an indication of what is causing the issue.

Comment: You need to [read this](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt2.html)

Comment: Thank you for the source @Mat'sMug

Comment: `For i = 2 To Rows.count` you're looping over every row on the sheet (>1M)  Try `For i = 2 To rng.Rows.count`  And `Mid()` is the least of your issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G), type:

```
? Rows.Count
1048576
```

That's the number of rows you are looping.

Wherever you used `Rows.Count`, use this instead:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

or assign that to a Long variable `numRows` and use that.

[Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) would have helped finding the issue, with a breakpoint in the loop.

Comment: Might be worth noting the issue with `UsedRange` and worksheet bloat - complete personal preference but I tend to use `.End(xlUp)` or `.Find("*")` methods to get the row count when looping. Could add those to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a *better* implementation however you should be aware that `Mid()` returns a `Variant` and your code then uses **implicit** conversion to return the `String` version.

If you use the string version of this function: `Mid$()` *(notice the dollar sign)* then the return type is **explicit** and always returned as a string. This *can be* marginally faster in high repeptitions of code.